# How do i dd contents in meta tag in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

how can check what are the data inside content?
i tried `{{ dd(content) }}` but it did not work. I want to view this content i got from db table

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{DB::table('seodefault')->pluck('meta_keywords')->first()}}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to define `$meta_keyword` from controller then return it to blade.